# PHP function to safely return a float from string

Tags: php, type-conversion

Let's say I have a form where I ask for a product's price. Basically, I don't consider the case where the user adds the thousands comma, that is: 1,000.00 or 1,000,000.00

I just consider the case where the user inputs 1000.00 or 1000,00 or 1000000.00 but never 1,000.00, or 10,000,000.00 or, even worst, 10.000.000,00

I came up with this function.

```
function getPrice($price)
{
    if (is_string($price)) {
        if (strpos($price, ",") !== false) {
            $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
        }
    }
    return (is_numeric($price)) ? floatval($price) : false;
}
```

Do you consider safe this function? Can you point improovements?

Comment: @Devon read the question again... He's not considering the 1,000.00 case just 1000.00

Comment: @Jackowski, you're right, I skimmed through the first  time.

Comment: The string replacement is unnecessary, floatval will already treat `,` or `.` as the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function looks OK to me except the last line with `floatval`.

My main consideration about this approach is that `PHP` will not represent float correctly thanks to: `floatval`, casting to `float` or arithmetic operations with float variables.

For example `PHP` may convert 10000.00 to 9999,99 depending on the precision set. (you can read more about this here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

If you need this prices for some arithmetic calculations after parsing them to `FLOAT` (in `getPrice` function) and you need **precision** then my advice is to avoid parsing to `FLOAT` and either:

- leave them as string and do the calculations with strings
- use `BC MATH` extension for more precise math operations in php

Comment: +1 for considering the precision, which I did not. I'll remove the floatval() because I'll do arithmetic operations with that number. Also, +1 for the link and the mention of the BC Math extension.